# How to make BeautifulSoup XMLFormatter preserve entities

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to preserve the order of attributes in an XML document.
As per the documentation I tried the following.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import XMLFormatter

class UnsortedAttributes(XMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p foo="1" bar="2">&amp;</p>', 'xml')
print(soup.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()))
```

This outputs `<p foo="1" bar="2">&</p>`, turning `&amp;` into `&`.
How can I keep the entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import XMLFormatter
from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution

class UnsortedAttributes(XMLFormatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(XMLFormatter, self).__init__(
            entity_substitution=EntitySubstitution.substitute_xml)

    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p foo="1" bar="2">&amp;</p>', 'xml')
print(soup.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()))
```